# custome php application in a subdomain under cakephp website

Tags: cakephp, subdomain

I have website developed in cakephp, now I wants to add a new application developed in simple php under a sub-domain like myapp.mywebsite.co.uk

How to make changes to .htaccess so that myapp will not interact with cakephp 
Please help me out.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The cakephp’s .htaccess is made to be ignored when you want to access already existing files in your webroot, so, in most cases you won’t need to change it, just upload your php files into /app/webroot and point the url to that filename.

Answer (score 0):

It can depend how your sub domain name is configured, if in doubt I would route it manually in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^subdomain.example.com$ /subdomain/index.php [L]
```

Do check it though, as I've written it off the top of my head! ;) This should go in the `htacess` in the root of the folder, so in your `public_html` or similar.